# IIS multiple sites - New website and port vs New virtual directories

Tags: iis, web-server, web-hosting, iis-8.5

I want to have two sites in the same computer, under `inetpub/wwwroot`.

Should I create two Web Sites running on different ports ( 80 and 8080 for example) and then link each domain to each of them.

Or should I make use of virtual directories and have them within the same port?

What's usually the way to go for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make two directories to place your site files in, in IIS create two websites and point each one their their respective site files. Create one app pool for each. Under the binding, add the HOSTNAME value you want each site to respond to, this is what allows IIS (iis 8.5+) to use port 80/443 for both websites without barking about conflicts.. Finally, add two DNS Entries, one for site1.example.com and one for site2.example.com. The IP address for both should be the IP address of your server (or public facing IP).